# Wait for response in a request in axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to run 2 requests. The 2nd one needs the information obtained in the 1st one, specifically the access_token.

I've tried something like:

```js
let access_token = '';

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: <url1>,
    data: <data>
    headers: {
      header1: <header>
    }
}

axios(config).then((response: any) => {
    access_token = response.access_token;
}

config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: <url2>,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
    }
}

axios(config);
```

The first request, as I see on the Network tab on the developer tools, is returning an `access_token`.
However, when the second request runs, that `access_token` is empty and therefore the second one fails.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the first request to resolve Aka finished and then you can make the second request using **async/await** logic.

Here's the code-

```
async function req(){
let access_token = '';
var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: <url1>,
    data: <data>
    headers: {
      header1: <header>
      }
}

const {data} = await axios(config);

access_token = data.access_token

config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: <url2>,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
      }
}

axios(config);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to call the second request inside of `.then()` of the first request, which basically means to wait for the first request to finish before starting the second one:

```js
const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: <url1>,
    data: <data>
    headers: {
        header1: <header>
    }
}

axios(config).then((response: any) => {
    const access_token = response.data.access_token;

    const config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: <url2>,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
        }
    }
    axios(config).then(...);
}
```